# How to set up Eclipselink cache coordination with Wildfly

Tags: caching, jboss, eclipselink, wildfly

I have set up a persistancce caching with Eclipselink on Wildfly 8. It works, but I also want to do cache coordination. I have the following setup for Eclipselink cache coordination in my persistance.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol" value="jms" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.topic" value="jms/MemberTopic" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.factory" value="jms/MemberConnectionFactory" />
```

However, when my entity is merged, no messages are sent by Eclipselink. I have logging set to "ALL", but nothing appears in the console.

I tried adding coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES to entity's @Cache annotation, but it doesn't change anything. Also tried using an MDB as suggested for WebSphere (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/cache011.htm#CDECEHFH).

The JMS topic and connectionfactory exist and Wildfly startup / application deployment shows no errors. For server clustering I run Wildfly in domain mode.

Comment: I'd like to note that some JMS message (type ByteMessage) is sent after merge, but cache isn't coordinated between the local server nodes running in domain mode and EclipseLink shows no log.

Comment: The message, as it turned out, was Eclipselink's attempt to use cache coordination, but since my nodes were using the topic separately it was ignored (Eclipselink does not process messages sent by the same service because it would be meaningless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ironically was in my Wildfly configuration instead - I didn't have my messaging cluster set up. I used the default messaging cluster settings from full-ha profile and set Eclipselink's cache coordination host accordingly:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.host" value="231.7.7.7:9876" />
```